# Restrict front client connexion with groups / roles in a realm

Tags: keycloak

I'm looking for a way to restrict user access to specific clients in a realm.
I know I can do it with client where Authorization is enabled (fine-grained authorization support) but it doesn't work when trying to connect from front (client need to be public and not confidential).
I'm using a javascript application to login from front-end.

Is there a way to enable Authorization for public client or a work around ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello @MrDiben, can you please describe a little bit more what type of application (public client) you like to protect? Authorization flows are very different for confidential clients which can hold a secret compared to public clients like HTML/JavaScript apps which are unable to keep a secret.

Comment: I'm using a client like HTML/JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will totally answer your question because it's still not specific enougth but it may give you some further help.

In case you're new to the topic, please see [difference between public and confidential clients](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_oidc-auth-flows) here.

The current best practice for public clients like HTML/Javascipt applications is to use OpenId Connect with the *Authorization Code Flow + PKCE*. HTTPS is of course a must have. I recommend you use a javascript openid connect adapter for this like the following for example:

https://github.com/panva/node-openid-client

Basically your authentication / authorization flow is shown [here](https://cdn2.auth0.com/docs/media/articles/flows/concepts/auth-sequence-auth-code-pkce.png):
When the user wants to login from your frontend client application first a unique verifier is generated which is only available to the exact user / browser session. This value get's hashed as a code challege. Then the user gets redirected to the login page of your authorization server (Keycloak for example) passing some parameters like a redirect uri and the challenge.

With successful login the user get's a session at the keycloak server which also stores the hashed challenge. Then the user gets redirected to given redirect uri (a path in your application) together with a code to obtain an access token. Back in your application you application uses the original value together with the code to get the actual token. The authorization server ckecks the value against the stored challenge and geturns the access token if it matches. You see the extra verifier is to prevent that anybody compromises your code fragment to obtain a token on your behalf.

Now you have an encoded access token in your browser app. Note the token itself is normally only encoded not encrypted but it can be signed. Those signatures can later be used from your backend to ckeck the token integrity but we will come to that soon. Roles, claimes, scopes and so on included in your access token tell you the privileges of the user/identity. You can of course use them to enable/disable functions in your app, block routes etc. but in the end client protection is never really effective so your real **authorization** ande resource protection happens at your resource server which is your backend (node, .net core, java etc.) maybe a restful Web Api. You pass your access token as a part of the http request header with every request to the backend. Now your backend checks the token integrity (optional) expiration time etc. analyzes scopes, claimes and roles to restrict the resource access.

For example a simple GET myapi/car/{1} may only need a token or can even be annonymous while a POST myapi/cars or PUT myapi/car/{1} may need a special role or higher privileges.

Does that help you out?